# Получить строки из JSON-ответа

Tags: python, json

Я получаю JSON-ответ для своей программы, но не совсем понимаю как могу достать из него: *'name': 'Olivia Rodrigo'* и название песни *'name': 'good 4 u'*. Спасибо большое.

```
{'device': {'id': '6890eef5ba942afc60daa1540a0cceff5b3e1f3e', 'is_active': True, 'is_private_session': False, 'is_restricted': False, 'name': 'DESKTOP-998F6JD', 'type': 'Computer', 'volume_percent': 100}, 'shuffle_state': False, 'repeat_state': 'off', 'timestamp': 1645930282396, 'context': {'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1EQncLwOalG3K7'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/37i9dQZF1EQncLwOalG3K7', 'type': 'playlist', 'uri': 'spotify:playlist:37i9dQZF1EQncLwOalG3K7'}, 'progress_ms': 33239, 'item': {'album': {'album_type': 'album', 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG', 'id': '1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG', 'name': 'Olivia Rodrigo', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AG', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CD', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CL', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CV', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FM', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GH', 'GM', 'GN', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IQ', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KR', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MN', 'MO', 'MR', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NE', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SZ', 'TD', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TL', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VC', 'VE', 'VN', 'VU', 'WS', 'XK', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW'], 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/album/6s84u2TUpR3wdUv4NgKA2j'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/albums/6s84u2TUpR3wdUv4NgKA2j', 'id': '6s84u2TUpR3wdUv4NgKA2j', 'images': [{'height': 640, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273a91c10fe9472d9bd89802e5a', 'width': 640}, {'height': 300, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00001e02a91c10fe9472d9bd89802e5a', 'width': 300}, {'height': 64, 'url': 'https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851a91c10fe9472d9bd89802e5a', 'width': 64}], 'name': 'SOUR', 'release_date': '2021-05-21', 'release_date_precision': 'day', 'total_tracks': 11, 'type': 'album', 'uri': 'spotify:album:6s84u2TUpR3wdUv4NgKA2j'}, 'artists': [{'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/artist/1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG', 'id': '1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG', 'name': 'Olivia Rodrigo', 'type': 'artist', 'uri': 'spotify:artist:1McMsnEElThX1knmY4oliG'}], 'available_markets': ['AD', 'AE', 'AG', 'AL', 'AM', 'AO', 'AR', 'AT', 'AU', 'AZ', 'BA', 'BB', 'BD', 'BE', 'BF', 'BG', 'BH', 'BI', 'BJ', 'BN', 'BO', 'BR', 'BS', 'BT', 'BW', 'BY', 'BZ', 'CA', 'CD', 'CG', 'CH', 'CI', 'CL', 'CM', 'CO', 'CR', 'CV', 'CW', 'CY', 'CZ', 'DE', 'DJ', 'DK', 'DM', 'DO', 'DZ', 'EC', 'EE', 'EG', 'ES', 'FI', 'FJ', 'FM', 'FR', 'GA', 'GB', 'GD', 'GE', 'GH', 'GM', 'GN', 'GQ', 'GR', 'GT', 'GW', 'GY', 'HK', 'HN', 'HR', 'HT', 'HU', 'ID', 'IE', 'IL', 'IN', 'IQ', 'IS', 'IT', 'JM', 'JO', 'JP', 'KE', 'KG', 'KH', 'KI', 'KM', 'KN', 'KR', 'KW', 'KZ', 'LA', 'LB', 'LC', 'LI', 'LK', 'LR', 'LS', 'LT', 'LU', 'LV', 'LY', 'MA', 'MC', 'MD', 'ME', 'MG', 'MH', 'MK', 'ML', 'MN', 'MO', 'MR', 'MT', 'MU', 'MV', 'MW', 'MX', 'MY', 'MZ', 'NA', 'NE', 'NG', 'NI', 'NL', 'NO', 'NP', 'NR', 'NZ', 'OM', 'PA', 'PE', 'PG', 'PH', 'PK', 'PL', 'PS', 'PT', 'PW', 'PY', 'QA', 'RO', 'RS', 'RU', 'RW', 'SA', 'SB', 'SC', 'SE', 'SG', 'SI', 'SK', 'SL', 'SM', 'SN', 'SR', 'ST', 'SV', 'SZ', 'TD', 'TG', 'TH', 'TJ', 'TL', 'TN', 'TO', 'TR', 'TT', 'TV', 'TW', 'TZ', 'UA', 'UG', 'US', 'UY', 'UZ', 'VC', 'VE', 'VN', 'VU', 'WS', 'XK', 'ZA', 'ZM', 'ZW'], 'disc_number': 1, 'duration_ms': 178146, 'explicit': True, 'external_ids': {'isrc': 'USUG12101245'}, 'external_urls': {'spotify': 'https://open.spotify.com/track/4ZtFanR9U6ndgddUvNcjcG'}, 'href': 'https://api.spotify.com/v1/tracks/4ZtFanR9U6ndgddUvNcjcG', 'id': '4ZtFanR9U6ndgddUvNcjcG', 'is_local': False, 'name': 'good 4 u', 'popularity': 95, 'preview_url': None, 'track_number': 6, 'type': 'track', 'uri': 'spotify:track:4ZtFanR9U6ndgddUvNcjcG'}, 'currently_playing_type': 'track', 'actions': {'disallows': {'resuming': True}}, 'is_playing': True}
```

Comment: Не вижу никакого JSON.

Comment: То, что Вы представили в вопросе, не json ни разу. Это в чистом виде словарь. Прочитать о работе со словарями в Python Вы можете на любом ресурсе посвященном азам работы с Python (коих не счесть)

Answer (score 0):

Вам должен помочь "Траверс для сбора указанного узла"

```
dt = {
    'collect': 'Apple',
    'next': {
        'other': 'nothing',
        'collect': 'Ball',
        'next': {
            'collect': 'Cat',
            'next': None
        }
    }
}
def collect(dt, ls=[]):
    for k in dt:
        if k == 'collect':
            ls.append(dt[k])
        elif k == 'next':
            if isinstance(dt[k], dict):
                return collect(dt[k], ls)
            else:
                return ls
print(collect(dt))
```

С сайта https://russianblogs.com/article/3094405532/#_43